# Clarification of how zip/archive files work

Tags: c#, file

Since this question was put on hold, and asked to narrow it down a little more, my question comes down to this:

What is the most basic way I can add text files to an archive file? I want to download emails in txt format from their inboxes for my users from their Gmail account (I have a service account setup and a self developed program to allow me to access their drives), but when it comes to emails, I do not want to spam their locally saved directory with every email they have. I'd rather save every email in a text format and pipe it into an archived file and be able to reference that archive file from my program.

I understand the binary writer / reader types, is that the route I want to go when using C#? Are there other / better options in C# that may be more efficient?

Comment: Why don't you just say "I want to understand how zip files work" instead of talking around it. The title of your question is misleading

Comment: Fair enough. I'll change it so it's a little less obscure. I was thinking along the lines because it's not an official zip file, but I get it.

Comment: I don't understand what your question is. Programs create zip files like they create any other binary file. They write data in a particular format, which they read later in the same format. What exactly don't you understand?

Comment: The zip file format: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zip_(file_format)

Answer (score 4):

I'm not an expert on the algorithms, per se, but the general idea is to find commonly repeated patterns in the file and index them.  So if you use the word "boondoggle" a lot in your file, the algorithm will create a table, put "boondoggle" in it and replace the usages of it with its index in the table.  If the index is only a couple of bytes then you have dramatically reduced the size of the file.  The basic algorithm used by ZIP is called DEFLATE.  You could google that for more info.

EDIT: I will point out that an archive (strictly speaking) is not the same thing as a compressed file.  A unix TAR file is an archive that just concatenates stuff together into a single file.  There's no compression going on with that.  That is why compression algorithms are combined with TAR (tar.gz, tar.bz, etc.) to get both.  ZIP does both archiving and compressing.

Comment: Good point about the archive file != compressed file, that was a concern I had about putting the word "zip" in the subject. Thanks for your input, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 3):

There's no magic in archive files. They're just files that have an (optional) index that maps files to offset in the main file. Zip isn't *just* an archive - it's primarily a compressed file format, which is also an archive. It's a file format like any other, really.

A simple format can be something like this:

```
2 ; Two files
File1,0,200 ; File one at offset 0, length 200
File2,200,50 ; File two at offset 200, length 50
<200 bytes of File1>
<50 bytes of File2>
```

That's it :)

Comment: Thanks Luaan! so if I wanted to create a custom file with 2 files to reference, I'd use binarywriter to write the 2 files together, then binaryreader.read to find the files based on the index of the file I'd be looking for?

Comment: @MichaelTucker Yeah, that's the basic idea. Of course, there's plenty of smart things you can add to your archives - compression, lookup by name, encryption, verification... tons of things to explore.